# How to use italic/bold version of installed font on Webstorm/Atom in mac

Tags: css, macos, fonts, mono

I recently got the Operator Mono font, and post installation, it works fine in Windows -

This is the `Operator Mono Bold` font, note the italics around the keywords `let` and `const` - 
[image]

In the dropdown, I also get a list of the font variants that I had installed -

[image]

I've installed the same font(and it's variations) on my Mac as well -

[image]

But when I head over to Webstorm on the mac, I only see "Operator Mono" in the font dropdown, and none of it's variations -

[image]

Here's the same code on Webstorm in Mac (no italics around `let` and `const`) -

[image]
How do I make the font setup similar to that in Windows? In the Mac, on Webstorm, there's only "Operator Mono" in the dropdown to select from, and none of it's variations, while in Atom if I enter anything other than `Operator Mono` in the "font-family" space, like `Operator Mono Bold` or `Operator Mono italic`, it just doesn't recognize it.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Which font format you installed in MAC?

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is almost 4 years late, but I just ran into the same issue. Hopefully this answer helps others.

If you go to WebStorm -> Preferences... -> Editor -> Font, there is now a "Typography Settings" section where you can select the desired font weight.

I personally like *Book* as it seems it is in between *Light* and *Medium*. It seems WebStorm is trying to infer the default font weight by looking for a style called *Regular* which Operator Mono does not have.

[image: webstorm font preferences]